# Changing server charset from iso-8859-1 to utf-8

Tags: php, mysql, apache, nginx

I have server with apache and nginx as proxy and in htaccess file I have clearly mentioned this code so that it can define server default charset to `utf-8`

```
 AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

but when i am trying to upload files other than  English character I am getting error in `filezilla` it says

```
  Failed to convert command to 8 bit charset
```

I have checked `filezilla` website and several forum all says this is because server header is set to some other charset and after that i checked the header and the header was  iso-8859-1 but i have clearly set the header as `utf-8` in `htacess` file. I have [checked](http://gtmetrix.com/compare/rfOsXZty/K7B9HFxY) and there also it says

Content-Type

`text/html; charset=iso-8859-1`

how to set the default charset to `utf-8` for entire server including mysql.

Comment: If you're on a shared host, it is possible that the `AllowOverride` directive in the `httpd.conf` configuration file is disabled, which means you cannot change it yourself, and someone else has to do it for you. You can easily setup the charset of your database by going into the Cpanel or PHPMyAdmin and creating a database.

Comment: @Luka i have dedicated server.please advise how can i change server charset to utf-8

Comment: You can try adding this directive `AddDefaultCharset utf-8` to the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` or `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`, depending on what you've got on your server and what version of Apache you're running. Are you also using FileZilla server as an FTP server? Of course, after you have changed something inside the Apache configuration file, you have to restart your server for the changes to take effect. The shell command to restart Apache: `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`. If you haven't got Apache2, use `/etc/init.d/apache restart` instead.

Comment: @Luka i am using apache 2.2 and i am pureftp as my ftp server

Comment: Take a look at the bottom of this file: http://pavel.grudina.info/dotfiles/pure-ftpd.conf. You should have something like this. If you don't, try adding it.

Comment: @Luka what is big5   # FileSystemCharset big5

Comment: @Luka how to set the default charset of server

Comment: It's an encoding with support for Chinese characters. I don't think you can set it globally. You can try changing it individually for Apache and PureFTP.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23028/discussion-between-raviloves-and-luka)

Answer (score 1):

The charset setting in Apache/nginx has no influence on FTP/SFTP uploads with Filezilla. If you're using FTP to upload the files check the FTP server settings. If you're using SFTP then you may need to check the user profile settings or even the settings on the server itself.

Comment: i have pureftp installed and there is no option to change the charset settings in whm\

Comment: how to set the default charset of server

Comment: This can be very host specific so you should probably contact your web host and ask them what you need to do.